# Why do I get this error in my UIcolour?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicolor

```
func changeColor(sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
}
```

> Generating Error :- `Type 'UIColor' has no member 'randomColor'`.

Comment: @user5473955-their is no method randomcolor for UIColor().thats why you got this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no method `randomColor` method on `UIColor`.

See the [`UIColor` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/) for the available methods.